# Executing print statement after scan statement in C

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void)
    {

        int age;

        printf("What is your age?: ");
        scanf("%d ", &age);
        printf("your age is %d", age);


        return 0;

    }
```

I am just learning some basic c programing and had a small question.
When i compile and run this code my console screen will prompt me for my age and i type some number and press enter and nothing happens. Then only if i hit any other letter on keyboard will my age get printed by last statement. I am wondering how come this is happening and how do i prevent that? I want to be able to type enter my age and display it as soon as i press enter after typing in my age.

I am new to C, just started messing around with it an hour ago so please forgive if this is a bad question.

Comment: Exactly the same issue as in the question linked above. Except that there they added an extra `\n` into the `scanf` format and in this case it is an extra space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `scanf("%d ", &age);` to `scanf("%d", &age);`

i.e. remove the space, you do not need it there.

A whitespace character in a scanf format causes it to explicitly read and ignore as many whitespace characters as it can. So with `scanf("%d ", ...` after reading a number, it will continue to read characters, discarding all whitespace until it sees a non-whitespace character on the input. That non-whitespace character will be left as the next character to be read by an input function.

Comment: perfect! how come the space makes a difference?:/

Comment: So according to that logic if i typed my age with a space after the number shouldn't it execute as i want it to@FredLarson

Comment: @user2733436, no, it will discard all whitespace until there is a non-whitespace character available. The space you press after your age will be eatten up just like all the others.

Comment: Sorry, my comment wasn't accurate. Deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You should understand that [stdio(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html) is [buffered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer).

Read *carefully* the documentation of [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Notice the role of space character in the control format string of `scanf`. You usually should prefer `scanf(" %d", &age);` to `scanf("%d ", &age);`  and you should test the result of `scanf` :

```
if (scanf(" %d", &age)<1) {
   perror("failed to read age");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Common practice is to *end* each `printf` format string with a newline `\n`. Or at least call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) appropriately.

BTW, compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ....) and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)